# Escrevendo e lendo arquivo via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arquivo

É possivel (se for, como) fazer o seguinte método com JavaScript?

- A pessoa digita em um formulário alguns argumentos,
- ao clicar em enviar ele vai executar um código JavaScript,
- nesse código a função vai pegar as informações do formulário e vai abrir um arquivo chamado por exemplo `info.txt`,
- ele vai escrever os argumentos do formulário nesse arquivo.

Também terá uma função JS já padrão que irá ler esse arquivo e definir o texto de certo lugar da página (essa parte eu sei fazer, só preciso saber como ler o `info.txt` via JavaScript)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

JavaScript é executado dentro do "ambiente" do navegador não sendo possível passar para o sistema operativo, onde efectivamente o documento existiria e seria possível ler e escrever no mesmo.

**O que pretendes *neste momento* não é possível.**

## Ler ficheiros

O máximo que consegues é ler um ficheiro presente no computador da pessoa que acede à página fazendo uso de HTML5:

## [Reading files in JavaScript using the File APIs](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)

Com a [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/) podemos interagir com ficheiros presentes num computador de forma a lermos o conteúdo do mesmo.

O suporte da File API está limitado a navegadores recentes, pelo que não é uma solução 100% eficaz para garantir que o teu projecto vai funcionar em todos os ambientes.

## Escrever Ficheiros

À presente data, existe um esboço em progresso para a [File API: Writer](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/) que virá a permitir a escrita em ficheiros:

> This specification defines an API for writing to files from web applications.

Que traduzido:

> Esta especificação define uma API para gravar arquivos a partir de aplicações web.

---

## Server Side Scripting

Dado a tua pergunta ser ambígua neste ponto, para o caso de te estares a referir a JavaScript no lado do servidor, podes fazer uso de [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) e da [API File System](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html) que ele fornece para trabalhar ficheiros no lado do servidor:

[File System Node.js v0.10.26 Manual & Documentation](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html)

---

<sup>Todos os links na resposta tem o seu conteúdo em Inglês.</sup>

Comment: Existe um projecto engraçado mas muito limitado para ler e escrever ficheiros no lado do cliente: [jQuery.twFile](http://jquery.tiddlywiki.org/twFile.html). Não vou incluir na resposta pois até à data requer applets para navegadores WebKit (Opera, Safari, Chrome) e não funciona em Internet Explorer. Mas fica aqui para mantermos olho nisto :)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Resposta excelente!

Answer (score 5):

Podemos criar um objeto [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) para fazer uma requisição HTTP a 
uma [Linguagem server-side](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguagem_server-side), que vai se encarregar da leitura/escritura do arquivo. Este exemplo vai ser em PHP.

Com o JavaScript incorporado no arquivo HTML, chamamos a função Ajax ao carregar o documento e ao enviar o formulário:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Exemplo Ajax só com JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name='myForm'>
        Trocar ano: <input type='text' id='ano-doc' />
        <input type='button' onclick='ajaxFunction()' value='Ajax!'/>
    </form>
    <div id='ajaxDiv'>Resultado do Ajax</div>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    /**
     * Inspirado em http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_and_ajax.htm
     *
     * @param iniciar Boolean Usando para inicio da página ou envio do formulario
     */
    function ajaxFunction( iniciar ) {
        var ajaxRequest;
        try {
            // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
            ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e) {
            // Internet Explorer Browsers
            try {
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                try {
                    ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e) {
                    // Não tem jeito
                    alert( 'Seu browser quebrou!' );
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        // Listener que recebe retorno do Ajax
        ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if( ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 ) {
                var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');
                ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
            }
        }

        if( iniciar ) {
            ajaxRequest.open( "GET", "ajax-exemplo.php" , true );
            ajaxRequest.send( null ); 
        } else {
             // Capturar valores e fazer chamada Ajax
            var ano_doc = document.getElementById('ano-doc').value;
            var queryString = "?ano=" + ano_doc ;
            ajaxRequest.open( "GET", "ajax-exemplo.php" + queryString, true );
            ajaxRequest.send( null ); 
       }
    }

    // Roda script ao carregar a página
    ajaxFunction(true);
    </script>        
</body>
</html>
```

A requisição vai ser feita ao arquivo `ajax-exemplo.php`, que vai devolver um resultado ou outro conforme seja um envio do formulário ou não:

```php
<?php    
function escreverArquivo( $arquivo, $ano ) {
    // Let's make sure the file exists and is writable first.
    if ( is_writable( $arquivo ) ) {
        // Write $somecontent to our opened file.
        $content = file_get_contents( $arquivo );
        $somecontent = str_replace( '{ano}', $ano, $content ); 
        file_put_contents( $arquivo, $somecontent );
        echo 'Arquivo atualizado.';  
    } else {
        echo "O arquivo $arquivo não tem permissão de escritura.";
    }
}

function lerArquivo( $arquivo ) {
    $file = new SPLFileObject( $arquivo ); // http://stackoverflow.com/a/9897022/1287812
    echo '<pre><code>';
    foreach( $file as $line ) {
        echo $line;
    }
    echo '</code></pre>';
}

$arquivo = "ajax-exemplo.txt";
if( empty( $_GET['ano'] ) ) { // Primeiro load da página
    lerArquivo( $arquivo );
} else { // Formulário enviado
    escreverArquivo( $arquivo, intval( $_GET['ano'] ) );
}
```

Finalmente, o arquivo `ajax-exemplo.txt`, onde `{ano}` vai ser substituído pelo valor enviado pelo formulário:

```
        GNU  GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE
           Version 2, Junho {ano}
```

O exemplo desta resposta vai mudar o arquivo de texto só uma vez, já que o `str_replace()` não vai encontrar `{ano}` depois do primeiro *replace*.

Answer (score 3):

Sei que o post é antigo e considerado solucionado, mas pesquisei sobre o assunto, precisava dar uma solução para um problema parecido.

**É possível salvar arquivo via JS?**

**Sim, é possível gravar um arquivo em uma solução *client-side*!**
Você pode usar soluções como o *FileSaver.js* para uma quantidade menor de dados, ou o *StreamSaver.js* para arquivos maiores.

Seguem os links dos repos:

**FileSaver.js:**
https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

**StramSaver.js**
https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar cookies utilizando `document.cookie="nomedocookie=valor";` e os cookies irão ficar sendo salvos juntos numa linha num arquivo txt no browser.

Para ler um cookie, utilize uma função como por exemplo:

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Ex:
Em algum momento você manda o código setar `document.cookie = "nomeusuario=Alexandre";` e depois em algum momento no seu site pode recuperar o valor do cookie `nomeusuario`  com algo do tipo:

```
<script>
nome = getCookie("nomeusuario");
alert("Bem vindo novamente " +  nome);
</script>
```