# Alterar coluna de txt

Tags: javascript

Tenho a necessidade de alterar o conteudo de uma coluna com javascript, para não ter a necessidade de usar o php com apache. Já que executaria com html e javascript.

Seria um arquivo com 10 colunas e somente modificaria a 5º coluna e que somente a célula que tivesse em branco.

`1|1|1|1| |1|1|1|1|1|`

O arquivo seria setado pelo formulário e alteraria a 5º coluna que estivesse com valor em branco com conteúdo de um campo texto do formulário.

E fazer isso para as próximas linhas do mesmo texto.

Comment: Publique também o código relevante, e explique melhor o que pretende sff

Comment: @Miguel Alterei a descrição da pergunta.

Comment: Se pretende mexer em ficheiros na máquina do cliente ou no servidor só com javascript, pode esquecer. Não dá

Comment: @Miguel No cliente, somente seria executado pelo html, sem apache.

Comment: Mas não dá para ler, gravar, alterar o arquivo. "O que preciso e somente um código para ler o arquivo, alterar e gravar"

Comment: Não entendi o que quiz dizer.

Comment: Corrigi, fiz um erro ortográfico

Comment: @Miguel Vou ter que partir pro php mesmo então. Tem alguma ideia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que dá pra fazer em Javascript é um método que altere o conteúdo:

```
var content = '1|1|1|1| |1|1|1|1|1|';

 alterContent(content, '123');
 function alterContent(content, val) {
 var add = [];
    content.split('|').forEach(function(v, e){
      add[e] = (e == 4 && (v == ' '|| v == '')) ? val : v;
    });
    return add.join('|');
 }
```

Se precisar fazer isso para cada linha, é só passar o método dentro de um laço e testar cada linha:

```
var content =  "1|1|1|1| |1|1|1|1|1|\n1|1|1|1| |1|1|1|1|1|\n1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|";
var linhas = content.split("\n");

/* passa a posição 2, se usar parâmetro: null,
   ignora a regra de linha, e testa todas as linhas */
alterarLinhas(linhas, '123', 2);

function alterarLinhas(linhas, val, posicao_linha) {
    for (var i=0; i <= linhas.length; i++) {
        if (posicao_linha != null) {
           if (posicao_linha == i) {
              linhas[i] = alterContent(linhas[i], val);
           } else {
              linhas[i] = val;
           }
        } else {
           linhas[i] = alterContent(linhas[i], val);
        }
    }
return linhas.join("\n");
}

function alterContent(content, val) {
    var add = [];
    content.split('|').forEach(function(v, e){
          add[e] = (e == 4 && (v == ' '|| v == '')) ? val : v;
    });
    return add.join('|');
}
```

[**1º exemplo JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/51pzn8vf/2/)
[**2º exemplo JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/yszzkLh4/)

Quanto a ler, alterar e gravar: [**veja isso**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7974/escrevendo-e-lendo-arquivo-via-javascript).

Comment: Interessante. Mais como faço para que ele somente na quinta coluna somente substitua valores em branco? no caso ali ele vai substituir todas as linhas pelo valor.

Comment: E nesse caso ele iria alterar linha por linha individualmente se eu criar uma caixa de texto e copiar o codigo para a caixa de texto do formulario??

Comment: Fiz uma modificação, para fazer isso somente quando estiver em branco.

Comment: Estou usando o código desta maneira para alterar dados vindo do form e o carácter que quero preencher no vazio. O problema agora que ele só altera na primeira linha já que o texto terá quebra de linhas. Já fiz varias alterações mais tudo sem sucesso ou erros parciais.

Comment: `document.getElementById("FormAlterar").onclick = function(e) {
        var content_branco = document.getElementById("campo").value;
        var dado = document.getElementById("dado").value;


 document.getElementById('retorno').innerHTML = alterContent(content_branco, dado);
 function alterContent(content, val) {
 var add = [];
    content.split('|').forEach(function(v, e){
      add[e] = (e == 4 && (v == ' ' || v == '')) ? val : v;
    });
    return add.join('|');
 }
        }`

Comment: Você não especificou isso na pergunta, mas você pode fazer um método à parte que separe as quebras de linha "\n" ou "<br>" usando `.split()`, é melhor você editar sua pergunta e ser mais claro e objetivo para que possamos resolver seu problema de uma vez.

Comment: já especifiquei. Eu devo usar a quebra ao ler a linha, ou depois de altera-lá?

Comment: antes de processar o método de troca, você deve encontrar a linha que irá processar a troca, correto? Então, você precisa saber qual linha irá modificar, para isso, precisa ter alguma informação que o leve para isso. No caso, é o espaço vazio? Ou tem uma posição de linha específica? Preciso saber essa informação, para assim criar o método que irá validar a linha correta.

Comment: Seria '1|1|1|1| |1|1|' quebra '1|1|1|1| |1|1|'

Comment: Olha a resposta.

Comment: Posição de linha já que vou usar areatext no formulário.

Comment: textarea, é quebra de linha "\n".

Comment: posição de linha é só informar a linha do array, ao invés de passar dentro do laço: `function alterarLinhas(linhas, val) {
    for (var i=0; i <= linhas.length; i++) {
       if (i == posicao_linha) {
        linhas[i] = alterContent(linhas[i], val);
       } else {
        linhas[i] = val; 
      }
    }
return linhas.join("\n");
}`

Comment: Deu certo na veia. Fiz as alterações para aceitar os dados do formulario e boa. Obrigado.