# Como faço para Modificar um Arquivo json Usando JavaScript:

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

tenho uma ajenda ja retirei os dados dele com jquery agora quero criar uma maneira de inserir dados nessa agenda
obs:o arquivo html esta hospedado junto com o agenda.json

agenda.json:

```
[
 {
  "nome":"Joao",
  "tel":"998765432"
 },
 {
  "nome":"pedro",
  "tel":"991234567"
 }
]
```

javascript:

```
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
function jjson(url, callback){
   $.getJSON( url, callback);
}
jjson("https://robotoscar.000webhostapp.com/agenda.json", 
    function(JSON){
        ajenda=JSON;
        for(i=0;i<agenda.length;i++){
        document.getElementById("lista").InnerHTML+="<li>Nome:"+agenda[i].nome+"<br>Tel:"+agenda[i].tel+"</li>";
    }
});
</script>
<body>
<h1>Contatos:</h1><br>
 <div id="lista"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Não tem como, somente usando uma linguagem que rode no back-end, como php por exemplo.

Comment: @AndreFigueiredo seria melhor esta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7974/escrevendo-e-lendo-arquivo-via-javascript